# What should be done with inherited factory methods?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, polymorphism

Suppose I have a class `BasicDate`, and a subclass of `BasicDate` called `EuroDate`.  The difference between the classes is month-day-year versus day-month-year.  I know it'd probably be better to just have methods on the same class to output them differently... but that's not the point of this question.

`BasicDate` has the following `init method`:

```
-(id)initWithMonth:(int)m andDay:(int)d andYear:(int)y {
    if(self = [super init]) { /*initialize*/ } return self;
}
```

And the matching `factory method` then looks like this:

```
+(BasicDate)dateWithMonth:(int)m andDay:(int)d andYear:(int)y {
    return [[BasicDate alloc] initWithMonth: m andDay: d andYear: y];
}
```

But if my subclass, `EuroDate` which would use a `factory method` more like this:

```
+(EuroDate)dateWithDay:(int)d andMonth:(int)m andYear:(int)y {
    return [[EuroDate alloc] initWithDay: d andMonth: m andYear: y];
} //we can assume that EuroDate includes this init method...
```

This is all fine.  Now, we assume that both classes have their own `description method`, which will print `MMDDYYYY` for `BasicDate`, but `DDMMYYYY` with `EuroDate`.  This is still all fine.

But if I do this:

```
EuroDate today = [EuroDate dateWithMonth:10 andDay:18 andYear:2013];
```

This will call the `BasicDate` factory method that `EuroDate` has inherited.  The problem is, remember how `BasicDate`'s factory method looks?  `return [[BasicDate alloc] ...]`

So `today` polymorphs into a `BasicDate` despite me wanting to store it as a `EuroDate`, so if I call the `description` method, it will print `10182013` rather than `18102013`.

There are two solutions to this problem I have found.

Solution 1: Change `BasicDate`'s factory method.  Rather than `return [[BasicDate alloc] ...`, I can instead do `return [[[self class] alloc] ...]`  This works and will allow me to use this method for `BasicDate` or any of `BasicDate`'s subclasses and it will return the right object type.

Solution 2: `Override` the factory method.  Whether I override it to throw an exception or override it to do `return [[EuroDate alloc] ...]`.  The problem with overriding it is that I have to override every factory method for every subclass.

Which is better?  What are some downsides to the two possible solutions that I may be missing?  What is considered the standard way of handling this issue in Objective C?

Comment: You should look up the "designated initializer" pattern. That pattern describes how to structure subclasses and initializer methods and convenience constructors (i.e. factory methods).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should generally use `[[[self class] alloc] init...]` in factory methods to ensure that they create instances of the correct class. Note that `class` isn't a property (and in fact, there's no such thing as a 'class property') so the use of dot syntax there is inappropriate.

**Edit**

And as pointed out by @ArkadiuszHolko (and Rob, thanks), you should now use `instancetype` rather than `id` for the return value, to get the benefits of strong typing while maintaining type flexibility for subclasses. And by the way, Apple's naming conventions suggest avoiding using the word 'and' in method names. So consider rewriting your convenience method like so:

```
+ (instancetype)dateWithMonth:(int)month day:(int)day year:(int)year
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithMonth:month day:day year:year];
}
```

Comment: I fixed my dot notation in the question.  Thanks.  Objective-C isn't my native language.

Comment: And, as noted in @ArkadiuszHolko's answer, you should now also return `instancetype` in factory methods. Before `instancetype`, all factory methods had to return `id` to avoid warnings.

Comment: Should it be `return [[BasicDate alloc] ... ]` or should it be `return [[self alloc] ...]`?

Comment: `return [[self alloc] initBlah];` or `return [[[self class] alloc] initBlah];`?  If I use the first, will it return the right type when I inherit and call the method on a subclass object?  Or do I need to use the second in the superclass so that subclasses will return the right type?

Comment: @nhgrif Within methods _self_ refers to the _receiver_ of the method. Within *class* methods this is the _Class_ - not the _Instance_ (object). Thus, within a *class* method you can write `[[self alloc] initBlah]`. Thus, when `self` is actual a `BasicDate`, this is effectively the same as `[[BasicDate alloc] initBlah]`.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper So with `return [[self alloc] initBlah];` as the return for the factory method in `BasicDate` (and inherited to `EuroDate`), doing `EuroDate *today = [EuroDate initBlah];` calls the factory method returning a `EuroDate` object, and doing `BasicDate *tomorrow = [BasicDate initBlah];` returns a `BasicDate` object, correct?

Comment: First off: a factory method will call an init method, not vice versa. Please view it as such: If you have a subclass `Derived` from a base class `Base` and class `Base` has a factory method `+(instancetype) baseWithParam:` (and `Derived` has no factory method) and you invoke it like `id obj = [Derived baseWithParam:param]`, then object `obj` becomes a `Derived`. If the init method is overridden by `Derived`, which will be invoked in the factory method, then Derived's init method will be invoked. You should write a short example and debug through it ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Hmm, that should have been `EuroDate *today = [EuroDate dateWithBlah];` so using the inherited factory method not the inherited init method.  I'm still not clear on how exactly this needs to be done or what's going on, so when I have a chance (I don't get much time in front of a Mac with Xcode), I guess I'll just have to write something.

Comment: @nhgrif I believe you realized the problem correctly. One potential issue with inheriting class factory methods is, that the derived class should override the init method which is invoked in the class factory. If this is not possible (for example, the Derived class does not know which init method is used to initialize the Base, it should probably better override the class factory method and initialize Derived with an appropriate init method (which in turn calls the appropriate Base init method).

Comment: From [Cocoa Core Competencies](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/ClassMethod.html) `+ (id)myClass {
    return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
}`