# iOS Subclassing a Custom Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, subclass

I'm having trouble wrapping my thoughts about class inheritance. I'm suppsed to create a dashboard like interface in a app, and I'll have maybe 10 widgets/dashlets on that dashboard view. All those dashlets/widgets will have basically same look, with a title on the top, borders, row of buttons on the top and a graph.
Let's say I create a subclass of UI View called 'Dashlet' with properties and outlets, and create XIB file with proper layout and connected outlets etc.

Now I want to create several subclasses of that 'Dashlet' view that will only process data differently, and draw different graphs. My current code looks something like this:

Dashlet.h

```
@interface Dashlet : UIView{
@private
    UILabel *title;
    UIView *controls;
    UIView *graph;    
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *title;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *controls;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *graph;

-(Dashlet*)initWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params;
-(void)someDummyMethod;
@end
```

And in Dashlet.m

```
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    //Basic empty init...
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Dashlet" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
        //some init code
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now let's say that I create a subclass called CustomDashlet.h:

```
@interface CustomDashlet : Dashlet
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* test;
-(void)testMethod;
-(void)someDummyMethod;
@end
```

and CustomDashlet.m

```
-(id)init{
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)parameters
{
   self = [super initWithParams:parameters];
   if (self) {
      //do some stuff 
   }
   return self;
}
```

This, kind of works, but I need to override some of the methods declared in the superclass or even add some of my own. Whenever i try to do something like this in CustomDashlet.m

`[self someDummyMethod]` or even `[self testMethod]` I get an exception error like this:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Dashlet testMethod]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Am I even doing this right? Did I miss something? Am I supposed to make this work in some other way? If anyone has  suggestions, please feel free to share your thoughts, thank you for all the help.

Comment: Do you have concrete implementations of `someDummyMethod` and `testMethod`?

Comment: Where is implementation of [self someDummyMethod] and [self testMethod] methods?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451744/what-should-be-done-with-inherited-factory-methods

Comment: @jszumski  Well, the someDummyMehod is implemented in superclass, and it looks as even though I override it in subclass, a superclass implementation code gets called. Test method is a method I don't have in superclass, only in subclass, and whenever it gets called, i get exception that no 'testMethod' method found in superclass.

Comment: @SlavenkoMiljic: The exception method `-[Dashlet testMethod]: unrecognized selector` clearly indicates that `self` in `[self testMethod]` is a *Dashlet*, and not a * CustomDashlet* as you expect. You should provide a small self-contained example demonstrating the problem, in particular show how the object is created.

Comment: @SlavenkoMiljic What happens if your create a `SalesDashlet` using `initWithFrame` rather than `initWithParams`?  It works, right?

Comment: @SlavenkoMiljic: `[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Dashlet" ...]` is indeed the problem, because it explicitly creates a `Dashlet` instance, even when called from a subclass init method. Infinity James's (now deleted) answer comes close to it.

Comment: @MartinR thanks. I guess, in that case I'll just try not to subclass Dashlet, but to load it as a subview to my CustomDashlet which will be just UIView subclass I guess. Thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that

```
SalesDashlet *sales = [[SalesDashlet alloc] initWithParams:nil];
```

does *not* return a `SalesDashlet` instance, as expected, but a `Dashlet` instance.
Here is what happens:

- `[SalesDashlet alloc]` allocates an instance of `SalesDashlet`.
- The subclass implementation of `initWithParams:` is called with this instance,
  and calls `self = [super initWithParams:parameters]`.
- The superclass implementation of `initWithParams` *discards* `self` and 
  *overwrites* it with a new instance loaded from the Nib file. This is an instance
  of `Dashlet`.
- This new instance is returned.

Therefore `SalesDashlet *sales` is "only" a `Dashlet`, and calling any subclass
method on it throws an "unknown selector" exception.

You cannot change the type of objects loaded in the Nib file. You could create a second
Nib file containing a `SalesDashlet` object. If the main purpose of the subclass is
to add additional methods, then the easiest solution would be to add these methods
in a *Category* of the `Dashlet` class.

Comment: Yeah, the more I think about it, the more I realize that this is the way to go, and I got things set up the wrong way in the first place. Once again, thank you for the help, hopefully this will be more than enough to get me started.

Comment: How many variations of the same answer did you need before you finally tried it out?

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is with the

```
- (Dashlet *)initWithParams:
```

method it is because the base class declares it with a **Dashlet** return value, whereas the subclass is redeclaring it with a **SalesDashlet** return instance.

Always use **instancetype** as the return type for any init method.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `id` should be the return type for `init` methods, and `instanceType` should be the return type for `factory` methods.

Comment: @nhgrif: `instancetype` is OK for init methods. And even if you declare `-(id)initXXX`, the Clang compiler silently *assumes* `-(instancetype)initXXX`.

Comment: As Martin R says, the compiler is assuming (instancetype) when you put id in an init method anyway; so just put instancetype in and be explicit.

Comment: Declaring the return type correctly (e.g. as `instancetype`) helps the compiler to find errors. But it does not change the actual returned value.

Comment: @InfinityJames: I think your other (currently deleted) answer goes into the right direction. `initWithParams:` in the subclass calls `[super initWithParams:]`, and `initWithParams:` in the superclass *explicitly* loads a *Dashlet* instance from the Nib file.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you simply need to change following line in your `Dashlet.h` file:

```
-(Dashlet*)initWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params;
```

to following:

```
-(id)initWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params;
```

or better:

```
-(instancetype)initWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params;
```

Comment: Unfortunately no change. The problem appears to be somewhere in the line `self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Dashlet" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject]`

Comment: Is your nib file owner set to `CustomDashlet' class? Without that you can not access methods in this class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `init` methods.

```
-(Dashlet*)initWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params
-(SalesDashlet*)initWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)parameters
```

The return type on both of these should be `id`.

The problem you're running into is similar to trying to do this:

```
NSMutableArray *someArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

Despite declaring `someArray` as an `NSMutableArray`, you've initialized it as an `NSArray`, and as such, `someArray` will actually be an immutable `NSArray`.

So because your `SalesDashlet` init method calls its `super` init method and the `super` explicitly returns an object of type `Dashlet`, then the `SalesDashlet` will also return an object of type `Dashlet`, so you're trying to call `testMethod` (a method that only exists in `SalesDashlet`) on an object of type `Dashlet` (which doesn't know about the `testMethod` method).

Changing your return type to `id` will make the methods return an object of the right type.

---

As a note, you've done your `init`, and `initWithFrame` methods correctly.

```
SalesDashlet *mySalesDashlet = [[SalesDashlet alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
```

Creating a `SalesDashlet` in this way will allow you to call `[mySalesDashlet testMethod]`.

Your `initWithFrame` has return type of `id` in both super and sub classes.

Comment: I do not think so. How the return type is declared is only relevant to the *compiler*. I might be wrong, but I cannot imagine how a "wrong declaration" could cause a *runtime exception*.

Comment: The exception doesn't happen until he tries calling the method on an object that doesn't know that method.  I've run into similar issues (in a comment to the question, I posted a link to a question I asked myself where I was seeing similar issues).

Comment: @InfinityJames I'm not sure if that's sarcastic or not.  If you feel I've stolen from your answer, I'll gladly delete mind if you include the expanded explanation in your answer...

Comment: @nhgrif Thank you for trying to help, but unfortunately, same thing. It looks as though I can only access methods from the superclass. I'm on the verge of deleting everything and starting from scratch :)

Comment: @nhgrif Nah it was a joke. I just don't like to add 'haha' or 'lol' to things I say. You're right, the extra detail is a nice addition, I'd sort of like to know from the guy whether this is the solution or not though because his question was pretty unclear.

Comment: @SlavenkoMiljic Hang on... have you included `SalesDashlet's init methods` in the `SalesDashlet.h`?  And changed the `Dashlet.h` header to correct the `return type` for the init method?

Comment: @nhgrif: Changing the (declaration of the) return type does not change the returned object in any way. - But the failure of a *designated initialized* (as in the question that you linked to) might be a problem.

Comment: @nhgrif yeah, still, no luck, I might read a bit more that question you linked, I'm still trying to read connect all the dots. I'm doing something really really wrong

Comment: @SlavenkoMiljic It would be helpful to include the code in which you're actually instantiating these objects in the original question probably.  And did you try the `initWithFrame` method?  What were the results of that?

Comment: @nhgrif hey yeah you were right, when I try the init with frame method, i can do `[self testMethod]` and `[self someDummyMethod]`, but of course in that case I only get a black rectangle, instead of a xib view, but at least this is a step in the right direction. Thanks. I'll try to add some more code

Comment: I'm not sure if this is problematic or not: `self = self = [super initWithParams:parameters];`.  One to many `self =`.

Comment: @SlavenkoMiljic Given that the `initWithFrame` method works fine, are you sure you've properly change the return type of all of your init methods?

Comment: @nhgrif yes, I've changed, and tested, same thing, I think I'll start over with some tutorial or something for Custom class inheritance. To me, now it looks like problem might be in the line `self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Dashlet" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject]`. Thank you very much for your time and your help

Comment: I think you are right that the problem is that  super explicitly returns an object of type Dashlet, but changing the return type does not solve this problem.